# Want to make a function return a vector of arrays in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have made a function that returns a vector of unknown length containing arrays of 64 integers.

When I access the vector inside the function, I am able to access the arrays properly. However, when I make the function return the vector and then access the vector outside, the arrays in the vector not show the proper original data.

The move function alters the variable bb itself. All other functions such as GenerateLegalMoves work as intended. When I try printing the array before the return statement, i get the desired output. However, when I call this function and store the returned data in a variable, the arrays do not show the proper data.

```
vector <__int8*> GenerateAllBoards(__int8 b[64], __int8 colour)
{
    vector<__int8*> boards;
    for (__int8 i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        if (b[i] * colour > 0)
        {
            vector <__int8> lm;
            lm = GenerateLegalMoves(b, i);
            size_t size = lm.size();
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                __int8 bb[64];
                copy(b, b + 64, begin(bb));
                move(bb, i, lm[j], false);
                boards.push_back(bb);
            }
        }
    }
    return boards;
}
```

Edit: The main reason that I want to stick with the raw pointers is efficiency. I tried the same with std::array, but ended up with results which were not ideal (It took too much time). Incase you are wondering, this is a part of code that I have used in a chess engine.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not returning a reference to a function local? Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre] of the code instead of describing it.

Comment: Are you using something like `std::vector<std::array<int,64>> get_arrays()`? Anyway we would need a minimal reproducible example of the code that reproduces your problem to help you.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I have already made a huge portion of my code with plain arrays and changing them now wouldn't be feasible.

Comment: The variable `bb` is local inside its scope, as soon as the closest `}` its life-time ends and the pointer you save  becomes invalid. You should use the vector of arrays as suggested by @PepijnKramer.

Comment: Also note that `__int8` is a non-standard symbol. Use `std::int8_t` from `<cstdint>` instead.

Comment: Not doing what you think. The vector is a vector of ptrs, not arrays, and all have the same ptr and point to the same thing that is no longer valid. Also, you can't have a vector of built in arrays. You must create a class that contains a built in array. Or use `std::array` as suggested by @PepijnKramer

Comment: Refactoring code to make it correct should always be an option even if it takes time (there is no shame in recognizing you went down a path that is not working, it happens to all of us). Also  changing "C" style arrays to std::array shouldn't really be risky (and even less so if you have unit tests). Also note using owning raw pointers in C++ is NOT recommended at least use std::unique_ptr

Comment: Raw arrays don't work this way. Would using `std::vector<std::array<std::int8_t, 64>>` be acceptable? That would work the way you seem to want.

Comment: Is there any way of making the above work with the C style arrays? It will be easy for me to change the vector the vector to another datatype if required.

Comment: You can use a C style array as a member in a struct/class and it will copy when you copy the class.

Comment: You need to allocate memory from heap to the array. Currently, you allocate from stack and when the scope of array ends, the memory is returned to the stack and then you try to access invalid data. Instead just use `new` to allocate memory from heap into a dynamic array: `__int8* bb = new __int8[64];`. And make sure that you call `delete` on this array somewhere in your code to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: You are not storing arrays in that vector. `__int8*` is a raw pointer; you must not use raw pointers as a beginner. As Pepjin mentioned, you need `std::array<std::int8_t, 64>` as the type of `bb` as well as element type of `std::vector`. As you have noticed, C style array has lots of limitations; that's why we use `std::array` instead.

Comment: Yup in the end you have to replace your `__int8*` with something else to make it safe. You could put a `new int[]` in it but then you will just get memory leaks because there is no way to indicate in code who is responsible for calling `delete[]`. Probably you could guess where it needs to be... but really you shouldn't work like that; We used to do this before C++11 but the amount of memory leaks or use-after free bugs where haunting us all the time. The choice is yours but don't tell us we didn't warn you

Comment: You might want to read up on the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) specifically the bits about new/delete, raw (non-owning!) pointers and ownership

Comment: "When I try printing the array before the return statement, i get the desired output" If you do, that's really unlucky, because at most one element of `boards` is a valid pointer at any given moment. Unless you are doing it within the innermost loop, trying to print the boards would have undefined behaviour

Comment: I would advise using neither C style arrays nor `std::array`, but define a `struct Board` with appropriate member functions. That struct might have a `std::int8_t [64]` data member.

Comment: `move(bb, i, lm[j], false);` where this came from? What it does? I'm not familiar with this overload of `move`? I've seen this [move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) and this [move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move). None of this accepts 4 arguments of this types.

Comment: `vector<__int8*> boards;` -- `__int8 bb[64];` -- `boards.push_back(bb);` -- This combination of those 3 lines makes the code wrong. -- *I have made a function that returns a vector of unknown length containing arrays of 64 integers* -- Your code does not do that -- pointers are not arrays.  It looks like this misnomer that pointers and arrays are the same thing unfortunately led you down the path of writing code that will not work.

Comment: @MarekR The move I have used is not the std:: functions you mentioned. It is one that I had defined earlier.